# Save to database entities using addtotable C#

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

```
private CoffeeShopDatabaseEntities1 cse = new CoffeeShopDatabaseEntities1();

TblProduct product = new TblProduct();
product.Descrption = descrptiontxt.Text;
product.Price = decimal.Parse(pricetxt.Text);
product.Image = bytedata;
product.ProductType = (int)cbocatgrey.SelectedValue;
```

Now I want to save this `product` entity to the database using this code:

```
cse.AddtoTBlProduct(product);
```

but `addtoTBlproduct` does not insert in Visual Studio 2017.

It's working in Visual Studio 2010. Please help me

Comment: Is `AddtoTBlProduct()` as custom method? Which EF version do you use? And is `CoffeeShopDatabaseEntities1` type of `DbContext` or `ObjectContext`?

Comment: The `.AddtoTBlProduct` would *only* add the new `product` to the **in-memory** `DbSet<Product>` - it does **NOT** (and never has) store anything into the database. For that, you need to call `cse.SaveChanges();` - **THEN** (and only then) the data will be written into your database table on disk

Comment: for rbr94 its  objectcontext but the the data base it self dbcotext

Comment: marc_s cse.savechanges(); only to save on the table or add some code to save to the table

Comment: `cse.SaveChanges()` will save *all changes* that have happened to the object context (or DB context) to the database - inserts, updates, deletes - everything

Comment: but this didn't not working in my code it didn't save any thing

Answer (score -1):

you just have to write  cse.TblProduct.Add(product);
hope this works....